# Boolean Indexing but turns out to be some other operation

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to do boolean indexing
but..

```
np.random.randn(8).reshape((4,2))
Out[11]: 
array([[-1.13058416,  1.08397186],
       [-1.2730122 ,  0.78306498],
       [-0.05370502, -1.16723298],
       [ 1.01750955, -0.95029671]])

a=np.random.randn(8).reshape((4,2))

a[[2==3,3==0,0==0,1!=1]]
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0.18235299, -2.53482367],
       [ 0.18235299, -2.53482367],
       [-1.03752809, -2.2790847 ],
       [ 0.18235299, -2.53482367]])
```

What just happened?
I was thinking more like Bool indexing. What operation is this?
I am not asking to correct this to Bool indexing. Rather, Im asking what is happening in this operation? Is this legit?

Comment: What does `[2==3,3==0,0==0,1!=1]` mean?

Comment: `2 == 3` is interpreted as 0 (False), therefore `a[[2==3,3==0,0==0,1!=1]]` is equivalent to `a[[0,0,1,0]]`

Comment: exactly, arbitrary numbers just to generate bool

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am reading this now. give me sometime

Comment: No rush, I just noticed that you are still active on SO:) I occasionally ping active askers who don't respond to answers, in case there's anything I can add to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to think of `ndarray`s as buffed-up `list`s. Broadcasting and operations on arrays are automatically extended to lists involved in those operations, so you can add an array and a list of broadcast-compatible shapes, and numpy won't try to concatenate the two (as it would try to do with two lists).

One huge (and, for me, confusing) exception is [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Fancy indexing itself is already confusing to me (as someone coming from MATLAB), since it's odd that the following two give a different result:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
A[0:1,0:1]
A[range(2),range(2)]
```

The former is a slicing operation, and returns a 2-by-2 submatrix. The latter is a case of fancy indexing, and returns only a 2-element array, containing `A[0,0]` and `A[1,1]`.

Your question is related to something equally odd: lists and arrays of *boolean* values behave differently when used in fancy indexing. Consider the following two examples, along the lines of your question:

```
A = np.random.rand(4,2)
bool_index_list = [False, True, True, False]
bool_index_array = np.array(bool_index_list)
A[bool_index_list].shape
A[bool_index_array].shape
```

The former returns `(4,2)`, the latter `(2,2)`.

In the former case, since the index is a `list`, the boolean values are converted to corresponding integers, and the resulting values of `[0,1,1,0]` are used as actual indices in the matrix, returning the [first,second,second,first] row, respectively.

In the latter case, the index `array` of `dtype=bool` is used as you would expect it to be: it is used as a mask to ignore those rows of `A` for which the index is `False`.

The [numpy release notes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#numpy-1-9-0-release-notes), among other things, indicate that

> In the future Boolean array-likes (such as lists of python bools) will always be treated as Boolean indexes and Boolean scalars (including python `True`) will be a legal *boolean* index.

Correspondingly, the list-based indexing cases above give me the following warning in numpy 1.10.1:

> FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index

So the short answer to your question is that it's legit, but not for long. Stick to `ndarray`-based fancy indexing, and you should experience no bumps along the way.