# appending numpy array with booleans

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain what this code is doing?

```
   a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
   a[..., [True, False]]
```

What is the `[True, False]` doing there?

Comment: On numpy 1.10 and 1.11 this is the same as `a[..., [1,0]]` plus a FutureWarning.

Comment: and what does that mean?

Comment: [numpy boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

**Ellipsis Notation and Booleans as Integers**

[From the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection tuple of the same length as x.ndim. There may only be a single ellipsis present

`True` and `False` [are just obfuscated 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante). Taking the example from the docs:

```
x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
x[...,0]
# outputs: array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6]])
x[..., False] # same thing
```

The boolean values are specifying an index, just like the numbers 0 or 1 would.

---

**In response to your question in the comments**

It first seems magical that

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a[..., [True, True]]  # = [[2,2],[4,4]]
```

But when we consider it as

```
a[..., [1,1]] # = [[2,2],[4,4]]
```

It seems less impressive.

Similarly:

```
b = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b[...,[2,2]] # = [[3,3],[5,5]]
```

After applying the ellipsis rules; the true and false grab column indices, just like 0, 1, or 17 would have

---

**Boolean Arrays for Complex Indexing**

There are some subtle differences (bool's have a different type than ints). [A lot of the hairy details can be found here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html). These do not seem to have any roll in your code, but they are interesting in figuring out how numpy indexing works.

In particular, this line is probably what you're looking for:

> In the future Boolean array-likes (such as lists of python bools) will
>   always be treated as Boolean indexes

[On this page,](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) they talk about **boolean arrays**, which are quite complex as an indexing tool

> Boolean arrays used as indices are treated in a different manner
>   entirely than index arrays. Boolean arrays must be of the same shape
>   as the initial dimensions of the array being indexed

Skipping down a bit

> Unlike in the case of integer index arrays, in the boolean case, the
>   result is a 1-D array containing all the elements in the indexed array
>   corresponding to all the true elements in the boolean array. The
>   elements in the indexed array are always iterated and returned in
>   row-major (C-style) order. The result is also identical to
>   y[np.nonzero(b)]. As with index arrays, what is returned is a copy of
>   the data, not a view as one gets with slices.

Comment: If that's the case then why does `a[..., [True, True]]` returns 
`array([[2, 2], [4, 4]])`

Comment: @JRR sorry, didn't mean to cut that answer short submitted too soon

Comment: @JRR you can confirm that a[..., [True, True]] evaluates the same way as a[..., [1, 1]], correct?

Comment: @en_Knight, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410469/boolean-indexing-but-turns-out-to-be-some-other-operation), when the index is a list, the boolean values are converted to corresponding integers, and the resulting values are used as actual indices in the matrix. And I also personally verified from my side, they are the same indeed.

Comment: @MaThMaX we're on the same page, right? That bottom section isn't to confuse people, it's just to help clarify if some of the numpy terminology seems scary. If it's unclear I can clean it up or remove it... it's just fun to dive down the numpy rabbit hole :)

Comment: @en_Knight, yes, we are on the same page. I think it is fine to have the bottom section.